# How do I specify `env_vars` in `devtools::check()`

Tags: r

Using

```
devtools::check(document = FALSE, env_vars="_R_S3_METHOD_LOOKUP_BASEENV_AFTER_GLOBALENV_= TRUE")
```

Doesn't appear to set the `env_vars` correctly, as the (pertinent) output I get is:

```
Setting env vars --------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_ : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_: FALSE
                        : _R_S3_METHOD_LOOKUP_BASEENV_AFTER_GLOBALENV_= TRUE
```

I would expect if the specification was correct in the call I'd see:

```
Setting env vars --------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                      : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                     : FALSE
_R_S3_METHOD_LOOKUP_BASEENV_AFTER_GLOBALENV_ : TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an example from the [R package rhub.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rhub/rhub.pdf)

**Usage**

```
check_for_cran(path = ".", email = NULL, check_args = "--as-cran",
env_vars = c(`_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_` = "true",
`_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_USE_ASPELL_` = "true"), platforms = NULL, ...)
```

You need to put the TRUE in double quotes, the variable in single quotes, and put a c() around the entire thing.

So now I redo the OP call as:

```
devtools::check(document = FALSE, env_vars=c(`_R_S3_METHOD_LOOKUP_BASEENV_AFTER_GLOBALENV_`= "TRUE"))
```

and get

```
Setting env vars --------------------------------------------
_R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_                     : FALSE
_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_                    : FALSE
_R_S3_METHOD_LOOKUP_BASEENV_AFTER_GLOBALENV_: TRUE
```